# MS access multiple relationships between two tables

Tags: ms-access

We had an MS Access guru at our company who left for another position. Before she left she gave me a quick introduction on how to create queries from a sql server. I am really struggling with this and as I have no one to turn to at our company I was hoping you guys could help.

Hope you can help!

Thanks!

Comment: This a use of compound key - multiple fields are used to provide a unique record identifier.

Comment: Many thanks! Will look it up!

Answer (score 1):

Between two given Tables you can have one relationship involving two (of more) fields or two (or more) relationships each involving one field. Both cases are possible and have different implications.

The first case, as the first commenter pointed out, is typically used when you have a compound key in the master Table of the relationship.

The second case is typically used when you have two candidate keys in the master table, each of which is used as a master field in each of the two independent relationships.

In Ms-access the case of two independent relationships may be identified because it implies two table-boxes for the same table in the relationships pane.

Comment: Wow this was really helpfull. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well, keep in mind that when you build a query, it DOES NOT necessary mean that a enforced relationship exists here. (it might).

Further more, if you imported the tables, then again its doubtful that relations are defined in Access unless you use the relationships window to "enforce" such relationships.

However, when building a query? We will often join on two fields. When you build a query in the query builder, you are free to "make up" any kind of join you want.

Say I was given two different spreadsheets. One had some people, and another had a list of hotels.

Ok, so say we want to generate a list of all people in the same city as the hotels.

You might join between table "People" and say Hotels with city.

however, WHAT happens if there is more then one state with the same City name?

Well, then just join on City AND State!!!

So you get this:

[image]

So I not have some related tables here. I just feel like and want to, and need to join the two tables of data.

As such, we never cared or setup or "had" some relationship defined, but all we care about is creating and building a working query.

So, don't confuse the simple act of building some query with that of having setup a corrrect relatonships between tables.

For a working application? Yes, you most certainly will setup relatonships.

So, if you setup relatonships correctly, then you not be able to say add a customer "invoice" reocrd without FIRST having a customer record. You don't have to do this, but it is a very good idea for a working applicaton.

However, when dealing with imported data? You often may not have an pre-defined relationships.

Now, of course in "most" cases, a query that involves multiple tables will in near all cases "follow" what you defined as relationships in the relationships window but it not necessary a requirement at all.

As noted, when building a working application? Then yes, of course you want to setup the relatonships BEFORE you start adding data.

But for general data processing, and creating queries against say different tables of data you are slicing and dicing and working with?

You are free to cook up and draw lines between the tables in the query builder, and as such, often such quires will have zero to do with the relationships you defined, or in fact even when you don't have any relationships defined at all.

That above People and the list of hotels is a great example. I mean, it rather cool that I simple joined on both City and State, and did not have to write one line of data processing code for my desired results

(a list of people in cities that live in the same city as my hotel list).

So don't confuse what we call "referential integrity" and defined relationships. We define these relationships so it becomes impossible for you the developer to add a customer invoice without first having added the customer. And it also means that you, your code, or even a editing the tables directly will not allow this to occur.

However, when dealing with just reporting, or importing data to work on? Well, then often we will not have any relationships defined, but that sure does not stop us from firing up the query builder and drawing join lines between tables.

Comment: All the thanks in the world to you. This made it much more understandable to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask if the result in your example will be the same if you chose city and province from the hotels table instead of the peoples table when running the query?

Comment: Well, I can choose ANY column from the two tables. I mean, if I choose City from both, then I would get see two columns in the output called City. (People.City, tblHotels.City). So, we have to "define" what you mean by choose here!!!  - WITHOUT question which table we drop FIRST into the query builder is VERY important. and WHICH direction I draw the join lines ALSO can have huge effects.  So "choosing" columns here does not matter, and I am free to choose + display City and Province from both tables. In this example, then I would see 4 columns, but in this case the values would be the same.

Comment: So once you done a join, then you can pick + choose columns from either table. There is no real issue to freely choose columns from each table, and it really don't matter. However what will matter, and is VERY important is the how the join is or was made. So once the join has been made, then columns from either table can freely be picked and included in the output. So, choosing columns ONLY is going to determine which columns are included in the query. However, HOW the join is made, what kind of join is a whole different matter. What kind of join you make (left, right, inner) is a HUGE deal.

Comment: You have answered my questions so clearly. I absolutely cannot thank you enough for taking time to explain this so brilliantly. Thank you sir.